# Updating Powerpoint Chart's from Excel using arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, charts, powerpoint, vba

```
Set PPT = GetMePowerpoint
PPT.Visible = True
Set PPres = PPT.presentations.Open(PPTFilePathAndName)
With PPres

For i = UBound(varTbl) To LBound(varTbl) Step -1
    Set PSlide = .slides(varSht(i))
    For j = UBound(varTbl(i)) To LBound(varTbl(i)) Step -1
        With PSlide

            Set pTempSlide = .Duplicate
            With pTempSlide
                .Name = "Sheet" & i & "_" & varSht(i) & "_" & j 'Give a name to slide

                If varSht(i) = "Scape" Then

                    'check the count of columns in table for doughnut chart
                    'if columns are less than 6 then delete the extra doughnut charts
                    m = 0
                    For x = 1 To .Shapes.count
                        If .Shapes(x).Type = msoChart Then
                            m = m + 1
                        End If
                    Next x

                    For x = .Shapes.count To 1 Step -1
                        If .Shapes(x).Type = msoChart Then
                            If m > UBound(varMktReady(i)(j), 2) - 1 Then .Shapes(x).Delete: m = m - 1
                            If m = UBound(varMktReady(i)(j), 2) - 1 Then Exit For
                        End If
                    Next x
                End If
            End With
            Set pTempSlide = Nothing
        End With
    Next j
    Set PSlide = Nothing
Next i

ReDim tempArr(1 To 1)
ReDim tempArr1(1 To 1)


For i = LBound(varTbl) To UBound(varTbl)
    For j = LBound(varTbl(i)) To UBound(varTbl(i))
        Set PSlide = .slides("Sheet" & i & "_" & varSht(i) & "_" & j)
        With PSlide
            .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = varTbl(i)(j)

            CCount = 2
            For k = 1 To .Shapes.count
                '   determine if shape is a Chart
                If .Shapes(k).Type = msoChart Then
                    Set pShape = PSlide.Shapes(k)
                    Set pChart = pShape.Chart

                    '   check if Office version is 2010
                    If Application.Version <= "14.0" Then pChart.ChartData.Activate
                    Set pData = pChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
                    lngPlotBy = pChart.PlotBy

                    '   clear source range
                    pData.Cells.Clear

                    'check for Doughnut chart
                    With pData

                        If varSht(i) = "Scape" Then
                            tempArr = varMktReady(i)(j)
                            tempArr1 = Application.Index(tempArr, 0, 1)
                            tempArr2 = Application.Index(tempArr, 0, CCount)
                            CCount = CCount + 1

                            '   reset sourcedata range of chart and copy table array
                            'If Application.Version <= "14.0" Then
                                pChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(UBound(tempArr1, 1) + 2, 2)).Address(, , , xlExternal), PlotBy:=lngPlotBy
                            'Else
                            '    pChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(UBound(tempArr1, 1) + 2, 2)), PlotBy:=lngPlotBy
                            'End If
                            .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(UBound(tempArr1, 1) + 2, 1)) = tempArr1
                            .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(UBound(tempArr1, 1) + 2, 2)) = tempArr2
                            .Parent.Close
                            pChart.Refresh
                            WaitSeconds 3
                        Else
                            '   reset sourcedata range of chart and copy table array
                            'If Application.Version <= "14.0" Then
                                pChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(UBound(varMktReady(i)(j), 1) + 2, UBound(varMktReady(i)(j), 2))).Address(, , , xlExternal), PlotBy:=lngPlotBy
                            'Else
                            '    pChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(UBound(varMktReady(i)(j), 1) + 2, UBound(varMktReady(i)(j), 2))), PlotBy:=lngPlotBy
                            'End If
                            .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(UBound(varMktReady(i)(j), 1) + 2, UBound(varMktReady(i)(j), 2))) = varMktReady(i)(j)
                            .Parent.Close
                            pChart.Refresh
                            WaitSeconds 3
                        End If
                    End With
                    Set pData = Nothing
                    Set pChart = Nothing
                End If
            Next k
        End With
    Next j
Next i

'.....

Public Sub WaitSeconds(intSeconds As Integer)
  On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

  Dim datTime As Date

  datTime = DateAdd("s", intSeconds, Now)

  Do
    Sleep 100
  Loop Until Now >= datTime

PROC_EXIT:
  Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:
  MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & ". " & Err.Description, , "modDateTime.WaitSeconds"
  Resume PROC_EXIT
End Sub
```

i have written the above (snippet shows only powerpoint code part) code in excel which opens another workbook, from each worksheet (total 4 sheets), picks different tables into a jagged array.
then this code opens a powerpoint template which has 4 diff chart slides and then duplicates these slides based on the table array count for the 4 different sheets. 
once the slides are duplicated (~354 slides), the array is looped and each slide is selected and necessary table data from array is put into each Chart datasheet.

however the problem is, the code takes a lot of time (~1 hour) to update the chart datasheets. most times excel crashes.

When i saw task-manager, i found the reason being "automation" as everytime the chartdata was being activated and array dumped into datasheet, an external excel copy was being created. even if i tried closing the chart excel workbook, i could see multiple copies of excel process piling up. i tried WAIT, DoEvents and now SLEEP, but still most times excel hangs, unless i increase sleep to 10 secs - but that makes the chart updation too long.

1] how do i speed up updation of chart data?
2] is there a way to use named range in powerpoint chart workbook and then do a pastespecial paste:=values ?
3] will a copy-paste of excel ranges (instead of using arrays) speed up powerpoint chart updation?

any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: My recommendation is to setup your charts and ranges in Excel and copy them as ppPasteEnhancedMetafile into Excel.

Comment: It could be that you are not deactivating the chartdata Excel object.   You may want to not activate it at all but just directly change the data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are not deactivating the chartdata Excel object.
You may want to not activate it at all but just directly change the data sheet.

```
.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.sheets(1).Range("A2").Value
```

Set this equal to the value in your array

This is for 2016, but you can also use .Cells.

Without activating the chartdata sheet, you will not open another instance of excel.